# HTML produces white space

Tags: html, css, primeng

I am developing a page with Angular 2 and PrimeNG Design Framework. While creating a simple layout consisting out of a menu bar and a content part which should be placed below the menu and fill the whole remaining space. But anyhow there is a gap at the bottom as you can see on the picture and I can't explain myself why.

[image]

And this is my `HTML`- Code

```css
#siteContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

#menuContainer {
  display: table-row;
}

#p-tabView {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="siteWrapper" style="min-height: 100%; width: 100%; display: table">
  <!-- Top Menu Bar -->
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <app-skeleton></app-skeleton>
  </div>
  <!--Container for site content-->
  <div id="siteContainer">

    <p-tabView id="tabView" orientation="bottom">
      <div id="tabPanelContainer">
        <p-tabPanel>
          <!--tabbody-->
          <p-card>
            <app-display-widgets style="{border: #7A7A7A 2em solid;}" *ngIf="sheet.id === refreshCurrentSheet()" [dashboardID]="dashboard.id"></app-display-widgets>
          </p-card>
        </p-tabPanel>
      </div>
    </p-tabView>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful.  [Height 100% may not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785476/870729).  I'd recommend using the css units of `vh`, example: `height: 100vh` (a `vh` is 1/100 of the viewport height)

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin:0` to your html and body tag

```
<style>
    html, body{
      margin: 0;
    }

    #siteContainer {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: table-row;
      background: blue;
    }
    #menuContainer{
      display: table-row;
    }
    #p-tabView {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your code see if that will fix the problem

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your router outlet is maybe wrapped inside container fluid, and if so either change container's fluid css to your liking or remove the wrapping div/container